# Full-width Background Videos in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, webm

I am designing a website that uses a self-hosted background video in a 100% width container.  Works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox but fails miserably in IE (tested in IE 11).

The video is supposed to stretch width-wise to fill the container - maintaining the video proportions, however, IE simply places the video in the container at the size necessary to fill the container vertically.

[image: Screenshot of video stretching to fill container width in Chrome]
[image: Screenshot of video failing to fill container in IE]

[Link to Page with Error](http://sawyerfirm.ignitte.com/auto-accidents/)

Comment: Try adding a meta tag on html in head section.. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

Answer (score 8):

```
/*you can use this css.*/

.fullwidth-video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.fullwidth-video video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

html code here...

```
     <div class="fullwidth-video">
     <video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted="">
       <source src="http://sawyerfirm.ignitte.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Girl-Riding-In-Car-8-BW.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="http://sawyerfirm.ignitte.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Girl-Riding-In-Car-8-BW.webm" type="video/webm">
     </video>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can Use this i hope it works for you :)

```
 This is html code :
 <div class="video-frame">
<video class="video-box" autoplay  poster="video-back.jpg" id="bgvid" loop>
<source src="sample.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>

This is css code :
.video-frame { position:relative;margin:40px auto;width:100%;}
.video-box { position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); background: url('video-back.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover; transition: 1s opacity;}
```

Answer (score 3):

> SOLVED

I had same issue for width in IE: the solution i found is removing the additional custom css applied over the `<video>` tag.

This much code should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<video width="100%" height="" autoplay>
  <source src="http://sawyerfirm.ignitte.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Girl-Riding-In-Car-8-BW.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>

</html>
```

> Then try to remove any additional class/style applied over/inside your
>    tag

Answer (score 1):

object-fit: cover is not supported by IE. Use the following library, acts as a fallback for IE :

https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill

Comment: The answer seems ok. But where is the "cover" from?

Comment: object-fit: cover can used as css property for firefox and chrome but it doe not work for IE

Answer (score 1):

On IE set height to auto for video.

**On Other Browsers:**

```
.video {

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* HTML video tag */
    &__player, video {

        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover; /* IE not work */
    }
}
```

**On IE:**

```
.video {

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* HTML video tag */
    &__player, video {

        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto; /* IE change to auto */
    }
}
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<div class="video">
    <video class="video__player" width="400" muted loop>
        <source src="XXX" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
```